# Calculate integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-x} (e^{-\frac a b x} - 1)^{b} dx$ for $b>0$ and any $a \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

i am working on following task:

Choose any nonzero $a \in \mathbb{R}$ so the integral converges and for a given $b > 0$ compute
$\int_t^\infty e^{-x} (e^{-\frac a b x} - 1)^{b} dx$.

I am looking for reference material or some tips how to approach such problems (improper integrals of rational functions of $e^x$).

It seems such integrals are computable, as Wolfram gives back some answer when I don't give limits of integration. The answer I get back from Wolfram is given using hypergeometric function and I need this integral as a function of $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enforce the substitution $e^{-\frac{a}{b}x}\to x$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
I(t;a,b)&=\int_t^{\infty}e^{-x}\left(e^{-\frac{a}{b}x}-1\right)^{b}dx\\\\
&=\frac{b}{a}\int_{0}^{e^{-(a/b)t}}x^{b/a-1}\left(x-1\right)^{b}du\\\\
&=\frac{b}{a}\text{B}\left(e^{-(a/b)t};\frac{b}{a},b+1\right)
\end{align}$$

where $B(x;\alpha,\beta)$ is the [Incomplete Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).  For $t=0$, we have

$$I(0;a,b)=\frac{b}{a}\text{B}\left(\frac{b}{a},b+1\right)$$

where $B(\alpha,\beta)$ is the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).

Comment: Thank you! I understand now

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Letting $t=e^{-x}$, we have the $($ [incomplete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) $)$ [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: Lucian, thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately I can't see it. Could you perhaps consider my calculation? Let $s = e^{-t}$, then $ds = - e^{-t} dt$. Then our integral looks like $\int_{-\infty}^{-log(s)} (s^\frac a b - 1)^b ds$. I can't see how it can be rearranged to the form of incomplete beta function.

Comment: @zen-dev: $e^{-0}=1,$ and $e^{-\infty}=0$.